# How to rearrange queued installations in Software Center?

Tags: 12.04, software-center

Is there a way to rearrange queued installations (that are waiting to commence) in the Ubuntu Software Center?

E.g., I would like the installation that is waiting last in the queue to be performed after the current installation has been completed, that is, I would like to "drag" the last waiting item to second in the list, or to rearrange the list by some other means such that all the installations occur in the sequence of my preference.

Can this be done?

I am using Ubuntu 12.04.

Comment: This is a feature request. You should file a bug against the software center in Launchpad.